# How to change the java version in docker image or container?

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, kubernetes, openshift

In my spring boot microservice project, one of the microservice is upgraded to java 11 and it is causing some issue in my existing functionality. I want to change the version of java from 11 to 8 in that microservice. but I am unable to do it as its created as docker image automatically through jenkins.

In the Gradle file I have mentioned the java version as 1.8 but still somehow in the kubernetes cluster only for this particular service java is upgraded to 11.

confirmed the version of java by using following command in the server.
"**docker exec {container_id} java -version**"

please suggest me how I can change the version of java in docker image or containers?

Is it possible to change the java version just by running linux command? or is it require to follow some other steps?

Comment: if you can find the configuration used by jenkins then you can configure it otherwise need to follow some workaround which is not efficient.

Comment: Typically this is something that would be controlled in the `FROM` line of your image's Dockerfile.

Comment: @msucil you mean the jenkins pipeline script?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am not much familiar with docker concept. trying to get more information on what you have suggested from google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@RakshithM yes, Jenkins must refer the `Dockerfile` to build docker container, if you find out then you can do it as suggested by @David. for you reference https://docs.docker.com/language/java/build-images/ , any container refer to the base image which has the basic environment on which our application runs which basically starts with `FROM` in docker file.
eg:

```
FROM openjdk:16-alpine3.13
```

here our container is referring to the `openjdk:16` image which is `minimal linux environment with java 16` on the top of which other tools are included which is defined in `dockerfile`. so in your case if you find the `Dockerfile` then you can change it to the java version of your need.

Comment: We have used JIB tool to create the docker image. so in the gradle file of my project i have added the below property to change the version of java 11 to 8.                                                jib.from.image = 'gcr.io/distroless/java:8'                                                                                                    previously it was like this jib.from.image = 'gcr.io/distroless/java:debug'.                                           this solved my issue. Thank you for your input @msucil